# Running NginX (with Apache) and cPanel/WHM

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy

I was wondering if its a good idea to be running NginX as the webserver (on port 80) and Apache as the reverse proxy (on port 8080) with cPanel/WHM being used as a control panel? I also installed Nginx Admin so the configuration for NginX is managed by WHM. The reason I am asking is because I came across an article (http://kbeezie.com/view/apache-with-nginx/) which explains how to setup Apache as a reverse proxy but it states

> If you are using a control panel based hosting such as cpanel/whm, this method is not advised. Most of the servers configuration is handled automatically in those cases, and making manual changes will likely lead to problems (plus you won’t get support from the control panel makers or your hosting provider in most cases).

Anyone have any past experiences with this and can say if its good/bad idea?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from the fact that mixing automatic and manual configuration of a package will most likely lead to troubles.

I think it is not a good idea to alter your web server configuration files manually (I mean here the web server running cpanel/whm). You may face troubles that can not be easily resolved. You can proceed, but you have to know what you are doing and keep backups before doing large-scale modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this, there is a plugin for that which handles all the config for you. Is calleed cpnginx.com